# Ratio of concave functions

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Prat

Is the ratio of two concave functions concave, convex, quasi-concave?
In particular, I am considering:
$$f = (-x + \ln(ax+c)) / \ln y$$,
where x and y are the variables, nonnegative and a and c are fixed parameters.

What does it depend on?

Comment: Seems like a not yet completely worked out question, how about $f(x) = f(y) = 0?$

Comment: Have you calculated the Hessian?

Comment: @kimchilover how can you learn a function is quasi convex by looking at its Hessian?

Comment: If, say, the Hessian tells you the function is strictly concave, you know it cannot be quasi convex.  If it tells you the function is convex, you know it is quasi convex.  If the Hessian at a critical point has one positive and one negative eigenvalue, you know the function is not quasi convex.  Calculating the Hessian seems to me to be part of due diligence in posing a question such as yours.  It is a bare minimum of work you might be expected to have done.  What work have you in fact done on your problem?